# Dynamically generate mypy-compliant property setters

Tags: python, mypy, setter

I am trying to declare a base class with certain attributes for which the (very expensive) calculation differs depending on the subclass, but that accepts injecting the value if previously calculated

```
class Test:
    _value1: int | None = None
    _value2: str | None = None
    _value3: list | None = None
    _value4: dict | None = None

    @property
    def value1(self) -> int:
        if self._value1 is None:
            self._value1 = self._get_value1()
        return self._value1

    @value1.setter
    def value1(self, value1: int) -> None:
        self._value1 = value1

    def _get_value1(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

class SubClass(Test):
    def _get_value1(self) -> int:
        time.sleep(1000000)
        return 1


instance = SubClass()
instance.value1 = 1
print(instance.value1) # doesn't wait
```

As you can see it becomes very verbose, with every property having three different functions associated to it.

Is there a way to dynamically declare at the very least the setter, so that mypy knows it's always the same function but with proper typing? Or in general, is there a more concise way to declare this kind of writable property for which the underlying implementation must be implemented by the base class, in bulk?

Declaring `__setattr__` doesn't seem to be viable, because just having `__setattr__` declared tricks mpy into thinking I can just assign any value to anything else that's not overloaded, while I still want errors to show up in case I'm trying to assign the wrong attributes. It also doesn't fix that I still need to declare setters, otherwise it thinks the value is immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to simply omit writing `@property.setter` (this part)

```py
    @value1.setter
    def value1(self, value1: int) -> None:
        self._value1 = value1
```

one possible implementation would be to subclass `property` to automatically implement a `__set__` method which matches the behaviour specified in your example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as t


if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx


_ValueT = t.TypeVar("_ValueT")


class settable(property, t.Generic[_ValueT]):

    fget: cx.Callable[[t.Any], _ValueT]

    def __init__(self, fget: cx.Callable[[t.Any], _ValueT], /) -> None:
        super().__init__(fget)

    if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
        # Type-safe descriptor protocol for property retrieval methods (`__get__`)
        # see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html
        # These are under `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` because we don't need
        # to modify their implementation from `builtins.property`, but
        # just need to add type-safety.
        @t.overload  # type: ignore[override, no-overload-impl]
        def __get__(self, instance: None, Class: type, /) -> settable[_ValueT]:

            """
            Retrieving a property from on a class (`instance: None`) retrieves the
            property object (`settable[_ValueT]`)
            """

        @t.overload
        def __get__(self, instance: object, Class: type, /) -> _ValueT:

            """
            Retrieving a property from the instance (all other `typing.overload` cases)
            retrieves the value
            """

    def __set__(self, instance: t.Any, value: _ValueT) -> None:

        """
        Type-safe setter method. Grabs the name of the function first decorated with
        `@settable`, then calls `setattr` on the given value with an attribute name of
        '_<function name>'.
        """

        setattr(instance, f"_{self.fget.__name__}", value)
```

Here's a demonstration of type-safety:

```py
import time

class Test:
    _value1: int | None = None
    _value2: str | None = None
    _value3: list | None = None
    _value4: dict | None = None

    @settable
    def value1(self) -> int:
        if self._value1 is None:
            self._value1 = self._get_value1()
        return self._value1

    def _get_value1(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

class SubClass(Test):
    def _get_value1(self) -> int:
        time.sleep(1000000)
        return 1

>>> instance: SubClass = SubClass()
>>> instance.value1 = 1  # OK
>>>
>>> if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
...     reveal_type(instance.value1)  # mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
...
>>> print(instance.value1)
1
>>> instance.value1 = "1"  # mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int") [assignment]
>>> SubClass.value1 = 1  # mypy: Cannot assign to a method [assignment]
...                      # mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "settable[int]") [assignment]
```

Comment: @SomeGuy I'm getting errors with the normal `@property`. Did you add `@test.setter`? The type-checking is right here, if it didn't complain, then you would be allowed to do: `a: Test = SubTest1(); a.test = [C(), C()]`, which will cause complete chaos.

Comment: @SomeGuy replacing it with `@property` raises all kinds of errors, as expected - you can see that here in the [mypy-playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=be7ced983348e3bddc9e9533318f4fb1).

Comment: Ah, I see, so the problem is raised on the setter, which is why I didn't see them when I tried to write an example. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of inheriting a bunch of pre-defined properties from a base class, I would move all the logic surrounding each property into a custom descriptor class. (The following assumes Python 3.11 and `mypy` version 1.0.0.)

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Callable, Type, Optional, Self, Union, overload

T = TypeVar('T')
C = TypeVar('C')


class Descriptor(Generic[C, T]):
    def __init__(self, f: Callable[[C], T]):
        self.getter = f

    def __set_name__(self, owner: C, name: str):
        self.private_name = "_" + name
        self.public_name = name

    @overload
    def __get__(self: Self, obj: C, objtype: Optional[Type[C]]) -> T:
        ...

    @overload
    def __get__(self: Self, obj: None, objtype: Type[C]) -> Self:
        ...

    def __get__(self: Self, obj: Optional[C], owner: Optional[Type[C]] = None) -> Union[Self, T]:
        if obj is None:
            return self

        if getattr(obj, self.private_name, None) is None:
            init_value = self.getter(obj)
            self.__set__(obj, init_value)
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)

    def __set__(self, obj: C, value: T):
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)
```

Then you can define each descriptor similar to how you would define a property, by decorating the function that will return the value an initial value if none has yet been defined.

```
class Test:
    @Descriptor
    def value1(self) -> int:
        time.sleep(10000000)
        return 1

    @Descriptor
    def value2(self) -> str:
        return "foo"

    @Descriptor
    def value3(self) -> list:
        return [1, 2, 3]

    @Descriptor
    def value4(self) -> dict:
        return dict(foo=9)
```

The descriptor class is generic in both the class it will be used in and the type of the wrapped value.

```
x = Test()
reveal_type(x.value1)  # int
reveal_type(Test.value1)  # Descriptor[Test, int]
x.value1 = 3  # OK
x.value1 = "foo"  # error, x.__set__ expects an int, not a str
```

Comment: Something similar should be possible prior to Python 3.11, but `mypy` 1.0.0 is required to handle `Self` properly.

Comment: I'm also not positive that `__get__` is ever called implicitly with only one argument; the optional `objtype` value of `None` may be for convenience in calling `__get__` explicitly. If so, the type signature could be simplified a bit in that `objtype` need not be typed as optional. (Most, if not all, examples of descriptors I've ever seen ignore `objtype` anyway.)

Comment: Unfortunately if I try to subclass Test, like in this very simple example: https://hastebin.com/share/ajoxatagif I get `Signature of "value1" incompatible with supertype "Test"` on the subclass's function. Can you confirm that on mypy 1.0.0 this error does not show up? Because I'm on 0.991, the version before 1.0.0, and I cannot upgrade at the moment, but if it goes away with the upgrade I might bite the bullet.

Comment: I can confirm that 1.0.0 produces the same error, but I'm not sure if it's a *problem*. It feels like the same error you get when you try to change the type signature of an inherited method.

Comment: I wonder: instead of saving in a reference to the getter on the instance, what if `__get__` uses the `objtype` argument to access the getter? Then you could simply override the getter in the subclass, leaving the descriptor itself unchanged. (If you do that, I think you would stop using `Descriptor` as a decorator, and write something like `value1 = Descriptor()`, then make sure you define a method like `get_value1` separately.)